# How to use setOnItemClickListener and setOnTouchListener both in Gridview case?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onitemclicklistener

I have a `GridView` and I want to access SD card on clicking it. I have used `setOnItemClickListener` for access a memory card folder. I also want to access element `setOnTouchListener` for drag and drop.

```
grid1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                public void onItemClick(TwoWayAdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
                {
                    File F_new=listFile[position].getAbsoluteFile();
                    System.out.println("path"+F_new);

                    makefolder_method(MainActivity.mcontext, F_new);
                    Current_path_vault=F_new;
                }
            });


 grid1.setOnTouchListener(new MyClickListener());
```

public class MyClickListener implements OnTouchListener {

```
// called when the item is long-clicked


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    // create it from the object's tag
    float currentXPosition = event.getX();
    float currentYPosition = event.getY();
    int position = FindPeopleFragment_next.grid1.pointToPosition((int) currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);
    View v = FindPeopleFragment_next.grid1.getChildAt(position);

     ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item("" + position); // here you send any data you want, I sent position
     String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_HTML};
     ClipData data = new ClipData("" + position, mimeTypes, item);
     View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
     view.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
     v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



            return false;

}
```

}

Comment: Are you able to call setOnItemClickListener? What about setOnTouchListener are you able to call it?

Comment: @rizzz86 i want to grid view item drag and drop like for drag and drop i want to add item in another grid view

Comment: So what is happening. setOnTouchListener is not called?

Comment: @rizzz86 when use  setOnTouchListener then doest not work  setOnItemClickListener. i am make a folder hider for drag and drop process and acess sdcard in a view like grid view

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` in `setOnTouchListener`.

The touch event that you are overriding in `MyClickListener` should return false like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         //Your work

         return false;
}
```